# How to correctly set the absolute path of a background-image when opening an html page directly from Android File Manager

Tags: android, html, css, file-manager, mobile-chrome

i'm creating a simple html page using droidEdit in Android, simple as that.
In this page there's a div with a background.
This background is an image stored locally, but the url must be (for a number of reasons) an absolute path, not a relative one, and in particular one like this: file:///sdcard/assets/images/test.gif

Now, if i open my page opening Chrome and navigating to file:///sdcard/index.html everything works perfectly, and i can see my div with his nice animated background.
My problem is that if i instead open index.html directly from the file manager, Chrome is launched and it correctly display index.html but the div shows no background at all.

I'm not an expert in how Android system works underneath the surface, but since the same code (with a different file:/// path, of course) works in Windows, i suspect that Android somehow uses a different url/uri system to handle locally stored files.

Is there any way to set the right (absolute) path of test.gif to make the css load it correctly, when i open index.html directly from the file manager?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Could you add the index.html file that has the background?

Comment: unfortunately i'm not at the computer right now, but i'm at the beginning of a project, so at the moment the html file has basically only one div, and the css has only the background-image rule ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing local images works when navigating directly to the file in chrome. It won't work when opening the html file from another page because of security rules imposed by browser. Checkout the full details here: https://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html

It can be fixed by base64 encoding the image using any online tool(search for `base64 image`) and using the result as background:

```
body{
  background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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')
}
```

Or uploading the background image to any image hosting service and reference the url.

Comment: Thank You for your answer :-) but then, why in Windows works both ways: either if i open index.html from Chrome, or directly opening it? I mean, there are no different pages, it is the same page, isn't it?

Comment: There is no difference in the pages, the problem is caused by the security configuration differences between android and desktop/windows. The Android way of dealing with loading local images is way stricter to limit the attack surface(checkout the blog). The background images aren't  loaded to prevent security issues. @Revenant

Comment: Did this solve your problem, if so could you mark it as answer? @Revenant